# Multiple AJAX Requests Without Refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that contains lines for company name address post code etc.

I have an option where if you don't know the full details you can enter the name and click search. This will get a list of all companies with a similar name via AJAX and return them to a modal window (not sure if this is the best method)

Each of the companies in the list has a button next to them to enable the user to select that company.

After click the company they want the form closes and I want the address details on the original page to be completed.

The problem is that the button on the modal after being clicked is refreshing the original page as i am use the method="post" command and this is removing any other data that is already in original form.

Is there a way to close the modal and update the original form without refreshing?

Thanks

This is my original page:

```
<input type="text" id="text1"><button id="button"> Search </button>
<input type="text" id="Address1">
<input type="text" id="Address2">
<input type="text" id="Country">
<input type="text" id="PostCode">



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Companies Found</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$('#button').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api.php',
        data: { text1: val1},
        success: function(response) {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the page i call via AJAX:

```
$company_name= $_POST['text1'] ;
$api_key = 'xxx'; // Get your API key from here:     https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk

$api = new companiesHouseApi($api_key);
$response = $api->send('/search/companies', ['q' => $company_name]); //  Process API request

echo'<style type="text/css">';
echo'.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}';
echo'.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}';
echo'.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}';
echo'.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}';
echo'</style>';

echo'<table class="tg">';

foreach($response['items'] as $key){
echo' <form action="search.php" method="post">';
echo'  <tr>';
echo'    <th class="tg-031e">'.$key['title'] . "<br>".'</th>';
echo'    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="3"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></th>';
echo'  </tr>';

echo'  <tr>';
echo'    <td class="tg-yw4l">'.$key['description'] . "<br>".'</td>';
echo'  </tr>';

echo'  <tr>';
echo'    <td class="tg-yw4l">'.$key['address_snippet'] . "<br>".'</td>';
echo'  </tr>';
echo' </form>';
}

echo'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the forms action to the page your on and change your javascript into a function like this:

```
<script>
function ajaxcall() {
var val1 = $('#text1').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api.php',
    data: { text1: val1},
    success: function(response) {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Process the form in php and check to see if the fields are blank (do your form processing here).
If they are blank, call the javascript function from php like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'ajaxcall();',
 '</script>'
;
```

If the form has the required fields, process the data and then use this to redirect to another page if desired:

```
header('Location: destination.php')
```

This is important, the statement above MUST be called before any html code (including echo from php)

On your ajax php page, I would recommend making 1 string of the data using a variable and then echo once the variable for example:

```
$str = '';
$str .= '  <tr>';
$str .= '    <td class="tg-yw4l">'.$key['address_snippet'] . "<br>".'</td>';
$str .= '  </tr>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: I'm still confused sorry. The modal displays the results of the Ajax call. I then need to close the modal and populate the original fields without refreshing.

Comment: as the modal is in the first pages code, you could run a javascript function when the ok button in the modal is clicked. the code would take the values from the modal fields and then set the values of the fields in the main page, finally close the modal. (the fields would need unique id's to ensure you put the data in the correct fields). this would run without refreshing the page as anything with get or post will need a page refresh.

Comment: thanks that worked I'm nearly there. I have managed to populate the fields however for some reason no matter what button i lick it only passes the value of the first button even though the values in each form are differet?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the modal form processing code please

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is reloading your page is because you have used submit buttons inside table rows wrapped in forms.

For one thing, that is bad HTML as `<tr></tr>` tags should not be immediately wrapped in `<form></form>` tags. But more importantly, if you have a submit button within a form, it will submit the form upon click (unless of course you do something to prevent it using JavaScript).

Here's what I propose you do:

**PHP**

Remove `<form/>` tag that is wrapped around the table rows.

Change the type attribute of your button to `button`. Most browsers will treat this as a non-submit button.

Attach a class to the table cells that you will need to copy into the form. For demonstration, we have given the last table cell an `address` class. We are attaching a class to reference it later.

```
foreach ($response['items'] as $key) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="tg-031e">'. $key['title'] . '<br></th>';
        echo '<th class="tg-031e" rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="Submit"></th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="tg-yw4l">'. $key['description'] . '<br></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="tg-yw4l address">'. $key['address_snippet'] . '<br></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

**JS**

Make use of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) to attach event handler to dynamically created elements. We will attach an `onclick` event handler to your table buttons.

Now, you know what you need to do when you click a button: (1) close the modal (2) populate form with company information using the button's table row as starting point of reference. I have no idea what address snippet is, but below should show you how you can copy content from your table row into the form.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api.php',
        data: { 
            text1: $('#text1').val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
});

$('#myModal').on('click', 'table.tg input[type=button]', function () {
    // get table row containing the button
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // close modal
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    // populate form 
    $('#Address1').val($tr.find('.address').text());
});
```

**Extra**

You may find [HTML5 data attributes](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/) useful here. You could store the company information in the `<tr>`.

```
echo '<tr data-address1="' . $key['address1'] . '" data-address2="' . $key['address2'] . '">';
```

And instead reference them in your JavaScript code using

```
$('#Address1').val($tr.data('address1'));
$('#Address2').val($tr.data('address2'));
```